# How to protect passwords in a chrome extension with no access to the internet?

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension which listens to webRequest.onAuthRequired. The goal of this extension is to avoid having to fill in these proxy authentication pop-ups as they are cumbersome and always come up when you switch networks. For the moment I developed the extension without saving anything to localstorage. password and login are stored in background.js variables so the user has to type his credentials every time he opens up the browser.

First : is there a way to prevent someone from accessing the source code ?coworker A can enable developer options, put a breakpoint in the code and see coworker B's password.

Second : how can I securely store the password with no internet connection (proxy is blocking any requests until you provided credentials). At best, I'd like this extension to work without the user having to enter credentials every time he opens up his browser.

Isn't there a way to use window's authentication as chrome does it to store passwords ? Windows credentials are the same ones the proxy needs.

What is Keepass' take on that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keepass allows users to lock/unlock their password safe via a master password. Even with Keepass, if a user walked away without locking their password safe (and without locking their desktop), a physically present attacker can easily read unlocked passwords. If you wanted to do it like Keepass, you could include an AES cipher and KDF implementation in your extension, to turn a master password into an AES key, which temporarily decrypts the proxy auth password. This would still be vulnerable, though, since the proxy password must persist in memory at some point to save the user from re-authing.

Comment: That said, I think your question about in a Chrome extension's ability to pass-through Windows credentials is an interesting one.

Comment: Ok thanks. So my last option is to have windows authentication do the work ? If windows could automatically fill the user's credentials when event onAuthRequested is triggered that'd work. Physical other coworkers would be able to bypass the proxy authentication if they get access to the computer (which is really not a big deal) but they wouldn't be able to see the real user's credentials.